# How to pass a Radiobutton from one activity to other activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 2 activities on android, in one activity I have 3 RadioButtons and a button called send, and when I select the first radiobutton  and press the button send I want to send that radio button and his functionality  to the second activity, and the radio button should be visible in the second activity until I decide to delete it from the second activity.

like:

Activity A:
-radioButton1
onclick(send)

activity B:
Received a reference of radioButton1 and his functionality.

is important to know that I don't want to start the second activity I just want to send a reference from the radiobutton from ActivityA to activityB.

Comment: Wrap the data which you need to send to other activity in bundle and pass it while initiating the activity.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 1):

The radioButton is a View, so it cannot be "passed" between activities. You have to create another instance of RadioButton with the same text as the selected before.

See more:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer passing only feasible data of radio button from Activity A to B then re creating radio button at Activity B. Bundle the data and pass in while creatingg intent to another Activity.